# Omit a part from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I'm using Codeigniter for my website and i want my single product url  like thi

`http://sitename.com/category-slug/product-slug`

So i register a route in `route.php` like this `$route['([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)'/'([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)'] = 'products/show';`

but, this route causing me problem this route is also being used by every route which is like this for example `http://sitename.com/admin/dashboard` which i don't want so i add a identifier in my route like this `http://sitename.com/myproducts/category-slug/product-slug` now my single product page is using this route and is not conflicting with any other route. Now the question is how to omit `myproducts` part from

`http://sitename.com/myproducts/category-slug/product-slug` to `http://sitename.com/category-slug/product-slug`

I know it is possible with `.htaccess` but don't know how?

Comment: You want to change the domain name ?

Comment: It was a typo. I edited question, basically i want to remove `myproducts` part from the url just.

Answer (score 0):

if you has a url´s like

```
http://sitename.com/admin/dashboard
http://sitename.com/myproducts/category-slug/product-slug
```

you can do this in your route file

```
$route['admin/:any']            = 'admin/int_rout/$1';
$route['myproducts/:any/:any']  = 'products/show/$1/$2';
```

but if you want to has the same route function for all and make every decision
with url´s like

```
http://sitename.com/admin/dashboard
http://sitename.com/category-slug/product-slug

$route['(.+)']    = function ( $param ) {
                        $pos        = strpos($param, '/');

                        if( ! $param){
                            $return = 'simple/url';
                        }
                        else{
                            $return = explode('/', $param);

                            switch($return[0]){
                                case 'admin':
                                    $return    = 'admin/int_route';
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    $return    = 'products/show/$return [0]/$return [1]';
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        return $return;
                    }
```